# Gradle sync failed , android studio could not create parent directory for lock file

Tags: android

after opening the project on android studio I got this error

> Gradle 'first app' project refresh failed
>   Error:Could not create parent directory for lock file C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle\gradle-4.4\wrapper\dists\gradle-2.14.1-all\8bnwg5hd3w55iofp58khbp6yv\gradle-2.14.1-all.zip.lck

I deleted the " gradle-4.4 " and download a new version gradle-4.4.1 but still  the problem appears

Answer (score 2):

[Android Setting Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J2uMr.png)

Open Android Studio > File > Settings > Under Service directory path is correct.

Make sure you don't have an offline location that is pointed to the wrong place.

Comment: found only settings reporsitory ,didn't manage to find that label can you be more specific please ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to give the jbr/ directory inside the Android Studio directory write permission like this:

```
sudo chmod -R go+w usr/local/android-studio/jbr
```

or wherever you have saved the android-studio directory:

```
sudo chmod -R go+w /android-studio/jbr
```